# How To Send Mobile Push Notification To Multiple Device/Token Using Firebase, JavaScript ,jQuery, Ajax, JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, firebase

I am trying push notification to Multiple Devices using Firebase, HTML, JavaScript ,jQuery, Ajax, JSON.
it's only work for single device/Token but not work for Multiple Devices.

> Error: {   "multicast_id": 8424906011038083000,   "success": 0,
> "failure": 1,   "canonical_ids": 0,   "results": [
> {
> "error": "InvalidRegistration"
> }   ] }

**Source Code:**

```
(function() {
angular.module("app", []).controller("Ctrl", function($scope, $timeout, $http) {
  
var Server_key = "";
var R_ID = ["device id 1"];  // ["device id 1","device id 2"] (getting error invalid device ID) 
var myJSONArray = JSON.stringify(R_ID);
var Device_ids = R_ID.toString();

  
  $scope.console = {};
  $scope.error = null;
  
  $scope.title = "FCM Push Notification";
  $scope.message = "this is FCM push notification testing msg!";

  $scope.send = function() {
    var btn = jQuery("#btnSend");

    var params = {          
      to: Device_ids,          
        notification : {
          body: $scope.message,
          title: $scope.title,
          vibrate: "[300, 200, 300]",
          priority: "high",
          icon:"1.png"            
      }
    };
    
    btn.attr("disabled", true).text("Loading...");

    jQuery
      .ajax({
        url: "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send",
        method: "post",
        contentType: "application/json",
        processData: false,
        dataType: "json",

        headers: {
          Authorization: "key=" + Server_key
        },
       data: JSON.stringify(params)
      })
      .done(function(result) {
        btn.attr("disabled", false).text("Send");
        $timeout(function() {
          $scope.console = result;
        });
      })
      .fail(function(error) {
        btn.attr("disabled", false).text("Send");
        $timeout(function() {
          $scope.error = error.responseText;
        });
      });
  };
});
})();
```

Comment: Have you read [Send messages to multiple devices](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send-messages-to-multiple-devices)?